# how to rename the SKU label?

Tags: localisation

This seems like it should be easier than I'm finding it. How can I change the label of SKU on a product page (and well, everywhere I guess) to "Article Number"?

I changed the label in attributes, I've changes the translate csv, but still it always shows SKU... weird! I'm using Ultimo if it helps.

Thanks.

**updates**

**in the view.phtml file** I have this:

```
<?php if ($theme->getCfg('product_page/sku')): ?>
                <div class="sku"><span><?php echo $this->__('SKU'); ?>: </span><?php echo $_product->getSku(); ?></div>
            <?php endif; ?>
```

If I hard code SKU to Article Number, I of course break the translation which enables the German version (which works!).

**In the back-end**, I have the following labels set:

```
Admin  - English  - German
Article Number  - Article Number  - Artikelnummer
```

If I goto \app\design\adminhtml\default\default\locale\en_US and the **translate.csv**

I have these entries:

```
SKU - SKU
```

So I changed them to `SKU - Article Number`, but still doesn't change in the frontend.

Comment: Have you changed it in admin and database for all stote views?

Comment: I think so... see my updates. Did I miss something?

Comment: Did you clear the translation cache?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the file Mage_Catalog.csv and translate it here.

Also, enable the template hints, find the real block name and the template. They can be rewritten by an extension. In this case add the extension translate as well.

Comment: adding to the Mage_Catalog.csv file was the only solution that worked from all suggested! Thanks :) Though, it does seem like the one from Simon should have also worked??

Comment: Glad to be of service. I have figured this case when support one of our modules. The module rewrites the block and none of the translations in this block worked. Reason was magento takes translation from current module. As there are several places where the same string is defined sometimes translation becomes tricky.

Answer (score 4):

Try it with these entries in your `locale/en_US/translate.csv`:

```
"SKU","Article number"
"Mage_Catalog::SKU","Article number"
"Mage_Sales::SKU","Article number"
```

Probably only one of the latter two is needed - just try it.

Comment: wierd, didn't work - but Amasty's did.

Answer (score 2):

It might be cached or hardcoded in your PHTML.
Open app/design/frontend/[yourtheme]/[yourpackage]/template/catalog/product/view.phtml and see there how that label is implemented .

Comment: thanks - I've updated my main question with the results.

Comment: Did you removed the Cache? What happens If you turn on the translation from the developer tab? Does it show the translated value in the modal?

Answer (score 2):

The best solution to rename sku is

Steps:

1. First go to  attributes in beckend.
2. select catalog->attiributes
3. Find Sku attibute in list of attributes then Go to manage label/optiona .
4. Change the title want you...

Comment: thanks - I've updated my main question with the results. This didn't work :(