# How to translate SKU# on detail page on Magento 2

Tags: magento2, localisation

I try to translate SKU# on my Magento 2 detail page. But it doesn't work. I found this for Magento 1:
[how to rename the SKU label?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/31054/how-to-rename-the-sku-label)

And need a simular solution for Magento 2.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Go to stores -> attributes -> product, search the "SKU" attribute and edit labels for your store view

Answer (score 0):

You can change product detail page SKU from

```
admin >> Store >> Product >> sku >> Attribute Properties >> Default Label
```

Change default and check it on product detail page.

Comment: It does still show SKU#... I flushed cache and reindexed already.

Comment: Add screen shot which you have changed in admin.